# I have problem with SpeechRecognition Python language selection

Tags: python

Got an error in Python with SpeechRecognition

> 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'recognize_google'

I tried many things, nothing worked except of I use r.recognize(audio) instead of r.recognize_google

r.recognize(audio) work only in english without need of google key.. weird.

Here my code

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import socket
import requests
import json

WAV_FILE = '/home/nao/recordings/microphones/mywavefile.wav'
mykey = "AIzaSyDbB#@34N1VaRW27HxA68rZW59UZ2qoPD8" # <-- modified key for my protection.

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.WavFile(WAV_FILE) as source:
audio = r.record(source) # read the entire WAV
try:
    sresult = r.recognize_google(audio, key=mykey, language="fr-CA")
    # sresult = r.recognize(audio) work in english
    print("I think you said:" + sresult)
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occure: " + str(e))
```

pass

If I put only

```
sresult = r.recognize(audio)
```

it's work in english, r.recognize_google don't seem to work at all return me this error

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'google_Recognizer'

I have the latest version of SpeechRecognition 3.8.1

in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages I got folder, it's where the package was installed
speech_recognition
SpeechRecognition-3.8.1-py2.7.egg-info

the name of the file I use it's ai.py nothing related to speechrecognition
Please help me...

I would like to use my google Key and language.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I can't found, if the language `fr-CA` exists in `speechrecognition`. Can you execute this code?

```
import speech_recognition as sr
print(sr.__version__)

r = sr.Recognizer()
filename = '/home/nao/recordings/microphones/mywavefile.wav'
sourcedata = sr.AudioFile(filename)
with sourcedata as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
try:
    print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " +
          r.recognize_google(audio, language='fr-CA'))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results \
           from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

After googling I found, that this error is in [open issue](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/383). Inspired by another [issue](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/196) I am updated code. So you can try to catch this error as shown in the code above.

`UnknownValueError` actually means that speech_recognition don't recognize anything from audio source. If you got this error from microphone recording I suggest you to the tune params such as `sample_rate` or `chunk_size` using pyAudio.

But if getting error after recording from file - I can't found solution

Comment: Thank a lot for helping me so fast.  here the result.

python test.py
3.8.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(r.recognize_google(audio, language='fr-FR'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line<br> 858, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError

Comment: Hi again, I don't use microphone always audio file so I don't use pyAudio.

It's was probaly the file corruption because I made some other test with other file and I got Forbidden error, after reading and searching, the key is something required by google if I plan to use other language.<br>

Could not request results \ from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}recognition request failed: Forbidden , it's seem that my key is not correct if I read the error message. I have create a key and place it in my code.<br>

Answer (score 0):

The following works. Using r.listen to provide the audio:

```
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:                # use the default microphone as the audio source
         audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
         words = r.recognize_google(audio)    # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
```

You don't need to worry about a key or language spec at first. Try making an audio file with a word that exists both in English and French. If it still don't work, try it with the microphone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from os import walk

r = sr.Recognizer()
#optional
#r.energy_threshold = 300

def startConvertion(path = 'file.wav', lang = 'fr-CA'): 
    with sr.AudioFile(path) as source:
        #print('Fetching File')
        audio_file = r.record(source)
        print(r.recognize_google(audio_file, language=lang))
startConvertion()
```